# How to show the logging output from DockerOperator?

Tags: airflow

I have a DockerOperator working but airflow does not show any logging statement of my DockerOperator like it did for PythonOperator or BashOperator when I run it with "airflow test".  However I can see the logging statements the same task is run.  How would I made the logger visible for "airflow test" as well?

Comment: Did you find an answer for it?

Answer (score 6):

Adding the following to my execution module displayed the logs in the DockerOperator for me.

```py
import logging, sys
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)

with DAG('my_dag') as dag:
    task_1 = DockerOperator(
        task_id='task_1',
        image="name:tag",
        auto_remove='force',
        tty=True,
        command="python3 myscript.py"
    )

    task_1
```

Comment: this worked for me, thanks!

note you must also `import sys` and in your DAG set the `tty` parameter of the [`DockerOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/docker_operator/index.html) to `True`

Comment: @spatialaustin It is easier using `tty=True`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this only solution available? OR anyone able to come up with better solution?

Comment: edited to show a complete example w dag and operator. happy to adjust as needed.